# Azure AD B2B for Analysis service and Power BI - External User invite

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, powerbi

Analysis service (i.e Analysis service installed in VM in MDX mode)  does support Azure AD Authentication. So automatically it can support Azure AD B2B authentication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/analysis-services/analysis-services-manage-users

If I have an architecture similar to describe in the link above and have  added user as guest user in the Azure AD B2B, they will have access to the analysis service.

If those guest user are coming into the analysis service for reporting need from a power bi tenant which is not the main tenant (i.e guest user own tenant)  where the Azure AD b2b is, will that be a problem? If yes what can I do to enable such scenario?

Currently i have Azure AD Tenant with external user enable. Analysis service in MDX mode is using Azure AD to authenticate. I have added external user to the Azure. When the external user logged onto their power bi (their own power bi tenant) and connect to the analysis service , their request is denied.

Answer (score 0):

> When the external user logged onto their power bi (their own power bi
>   tenant) and connect to the analysis service , their request is denied.

The user logged in A tenant, how can he be able to access the analysis service in B tennat. You need the identity in B tenant.

> Azure Analysis Services uses Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for
>   identity management and user authentication. Any user creating,
>   managing, or connecting to an Azure Analysis Services server must have
>   a valid user identity in an Azure AD tenant in the same subscription.

Comment: User(Lets called it User AB) who is logged into Power BI in Tenant A connecting to Analysis Service in Tenant B is added as guest user in Tenant B . That is User AB from a directory in Tenant A is also a guest user in AD in tenant B.